# How to disable some rules of an input method?

Tags: input-method, quail

I use `purescript-unicode-input-method` in Purescript.  However, I want the input method not to translate `->`, `~>` and `=>` because their Unicode characters look very similar.  Is there a way to disable certain rules of an input method?

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like the following:

```el
(defvar my-quail-activate-hook-done nil)

(defun my-quail-activate-hook ()
  (unless (member (quail-name) my-quail-activate-hook-done)
    (push (quail-name) my-quail-activate-hook-done)
    (when (member (quail-name) '("purescript-unicode"))
      ;; Remove the "->" binding.
      (setf (alist-get ?> (cdr (alist-get ?- (quail-map)))) nil)
      ...
      )))
(add-hook 'quail-activate-hook #'my-quail-activate-hook)
```

Comment: Hi, can I know what does ?> and ?- mean?

Comment: `?<char>` is the Elisp syntax for a character literal, like `'<char>'` in C.

Comment: Great!  Thank you a lot.  Can I know where I can find document of quail-map?  I tried describe-variable but it is not there.

Comment: IIRC it's not very documented :-(

Comment: Got it!  Thank you a lot!