# How to implement a function in `quail-define-rules` (for `set-input-method`)?

Tags: latex, functions, input-method, quail

I'm checking out `quail` (`set-input-method`) to write some LaTeX snippets (I felt it had some advantages over the others snippet options such as `yas-snippets`).

According to  the manual:

> quail-define-rules is an autoloaded Lisp macro in ‘quail.el’.
>
> (quail-define-rules &rest RULES)
>
> Define translation rules of the current Quail package.
> Each argument is a list of KEY and TRANSLATION.
> KEY is a string meaning a sequence of keystrokes to be translated. TRANSLATION is a character, a string, a vector, a Quail map, or a ***function***.

---

**Problem**; I cannot implement **function** on the `TRANSLATION`.

The following is my example script:

```
(require 'quail)

(quail-define-package
 "Test-Latex" "Test-Latex"  "tltx-" t
 "Test-Latex Keyboard Layout"
 nil t t t t nil nil nil nil nil t)

(quail-define-rules
 ("x"   "A" )                                     ;; <======== char works  
 ("a."  ["\\alpha"])                              ;; <======== string works
 ("al"  ["\\begin{align}\n\n\\end{align}"])       ;; <======== string works  
 ("eq"  ["\\begin{equation}\n\n\\end{equation}"]) ;; <======== string works
 ("Eq" (lambda ()                                 ;; <======== function NOT WORKS
     (interactive)
     (insert "\\begin{equation}\n\n\\end{equation}")
     (previous-line)
     ))
 )
```

**Question**; How to implement **function** on the `TRANSLATION` in `quail-define-rules`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @phils pointed out the list of files/function that used this functionality.

From them I used `quail-japanese-switch-package` in `quail/japanese` as my reference. And following function work somehow (TBH, not sure why it's working)

```elisp
(require 'quail)

;;;;;;;;;;; this the new function ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
(defun quail-equation-test (key idx)    ; key=keyword, idx=length

  (quail-delete-region)                 ; these lines apparently needed   
  (setq quail-current-str nil           ; to remove key.
        quail-converting nil            ; (not sure why all 4 is needed)
        quail-conversion-str "")        ;


  (insert "\\begin{equation}\n\n\\end{equation}")
  (previous-line)

  (throw 'quail-tag nil)                ; this is need for finishing up?
  ) 

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

(quail-define-package
 "Test-Latex" "Test-Latex"  "tltx-" t
 "Test-Latex Keyboard Layout"
 nil t t t t nil nil nil nil nil t)

(quail-define-rules
 ("x"   "A" )                                     ;; <======== char works  
 ("a."  ["\\alpha"])                              ;; <======== string works
 ("al"  ["\\begin{align}\n\n\\end{align}"])       ;; <======== string works  
 ("eq"  ["\\begin{equation}\n\n\\end{equation}"]) ;; <======== string works
 ("Eq"  quail-equation-test)                      ;; <======== function WORKS
 )
```

---

From my observations:

It seems first 4 lines in the function removes the keyword (in this case `Eq`)fully.

```elisp
  (quail-delete-region)                 ; these lines apparently needed   
  (setq quail-current-str nil           ; to remove key.
        quail-converting nil            ; (not sure why all 4 is needed)
        quail-conversion-str "")        ;
```

Without last line, `quail` doesn't work correctly after the `quail-equation-test` executed. Perhaps, it's something related to finishing up the state of `quail`

```elisp
  (throw 'quail-tag nil)                ; this is need for finishing up?
```

Answer (score 1):

If you keep reading...

> If TRANSLATION is a Quail map or **a function symbol** which returns a Quail map, it is used to handle KEY.

You were passing a lambda form instead of a symbol.  You need to define a named function and supply its symbol.  Furthermore:

> ... a function symbol **which returns a Quail map**

Which isn't what your attempt is doing.

Below are my comments from https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/73592/454 :

---

`quail-define-rules` is a macro, so I would expect it'd just be `("b" myfunction)` without the quote (as macro arguments are not evaluated), but this isn't something I've tried, so I don't know for sure how that argument gets processed within the macro body. You'll have to experiment and report back.

---

Documentation is limited. You will have to read and experiment. You will find information on quail maps in <kbd>M-x</kbd> `find-library` <kbd>RET</kbd> `quail` (see also <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>f</kbd> `quail-map-p`) and you can find what I think may be the only examples of a function value in <kbd>M-x</kbd> `find-library` <kbd>RET</kbd> `quail/japanese`. The function must accept two arguments `(key idx)` where `KEY` is the input string to be translated, and `IDX` is... unclear at first glance, but related to the key length. The examples in the `quail/japanese` library seem non-trivial. Have fun!

---

After a more general search, `indian-mlm-mozhi-underscore` in `quail/indian`, and `ipa-x-sampa-underscore-implosive` in `quail/ipa` seems to be the other places where this feature is used. (I.e. In addition to `quail-japanese-switch-package` and `quail-japanese-self-insert-and-switch-to-alpha` in `quail/japanese`).

Comment: Thanks for directing into right part of code to seek. I think I've figured it out. THANKS !!